# "Man of the Earth", is it an idiom?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> *And this guy was a man of the earth, so to speak.*

What does it mean to say someone is "a man of the earth"?

This is said by Martin Scorsese in an biography book called "Conversations with Scorsese" by Richard Schickel. I don't have any idea what it means. A bit more context - which I'm not sure can help - is: "Anyway, the landlord may have felt that my father was involved with underworld figures, which he wasn’t really, but he behaved maybe a little bit like that; my father always liked to dress, you know. And this guy was a man of the earth, so to speak. And I think also his wife liked my father. So all this resentment was building up. And then there was a confrontation."

Comment: Who said this phrase? Was this person an Englishman or someone from Europe? Where did you read or hear it? And what do *you* think it means? On EL&U we expect some effort in the form of research, context, or explanation from users. It also makes the questions more fun to answer!

Comment: "Man of the world" is an idiom, with a fairly well established meaning.  "Man of the earth" could be interpreted several different ways, and I would not consider it to be idiomatic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This is said by Martin Scorsese in an biography book called "Conversations with Scorsese" by Richard Schickel. I don't have any idea what it means. A bit more context - which I'm not sure can help - is: "Anyway, the landlord may have felt that my father was involved with underworld figures, which he
wasn’t really, but he behaved maybe a little bit like that; my father always liked to dress, you know. And
this guy was a man of the earth, so to speak. And I think also his wife liked my father. So all this
resentment was building up. And then there was a confrontation."

Answer (score 5):

On the simplest level, a *man of the earth* is someone who works the soil — a farmer or gardener. It is an [*epithet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet) that usually conveys dignity and respect, implying that the person so called has a special relationship to the soil and growing things.

In the original Hebrew of Gen 9.20, Noah is termed an *ish ha-adama*, ‘man of the earth/soil’, but translations of the verse are rarely literal. Thus earlier English speakers would have learned the expression from hearing about the verse rather than the verse itself:

> Noah is called in the *Hebrew* (in *Gen*. ix. 20.) Vir terrae, [*a Man of the Earth*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A55340.0001.001/1:7.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext), that is, a *Husbandman*; according to an usual Phrase of Scripture, which calls a Soldier, *a Man of War*; a strong Man, *a Man of the Arms*, Vir brachii, (Iob. xxii. 8.) a Murderer, *a Man of Blood*; an Orator, *a Man of Words*; and a Shepherd, a *Man of Cattel*.— Andrew Tooke, trans., François Pomey, *The Pantheon*, 1698, 162.
>
> Noah was a [*man of the earth*](https://books.google.de/books?id=X5kAAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PP14&lpg=RA4-PP14&dq=%22man+of+the+earth%22+-ipomoea&source=bl&ots=UvO9c2Y0IG&sig=ACfU3U2rfNLhy4mU65nuz_0MvMMmE56aRg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiogIuixp_gAhXJ_aQKHUutCKg4FBDoATAJegQICRAB), a husbandman, or one who tilled the ground.  — Alexander Cruden,  *A Complete Concordance to the Holy Scriptures*, 1839.

From its biblical use it essentially became an honoric for a farmer or gardener, including all the positive qualities of one “close to the soil”:

> Denis was in his late 90s and enjoyed marvellous health up to recently. Denis was a [*man of the earth*](https://www.tipperarylive.ie/news/obituaries/294984/denis-smyth-was-a-man-of-the-earth.html) and loved people calling to purchase flowers, honey and anything else that Dinny would produce at his farm. — Tipperary Live, 4 Feb. 2018.
>
> Williamson is a [*man of the earth*](http://www.montgomeryherald.com/news/article_8a1ec102-38c2-11e2-8a7d-001a4bcf887a.html), soft spoken, not much for crowds or awards, like the Elite Farmer Award he and wife Che Che recently received from Farm Bureau Montgomery. — *Montgomery Herald*, 28 Nov. 2012.
>
> The [*man of the earth*](https://youtu.be/YbXDk3i6hfk), the man of the soil
>    In his lonely allotment he labours and toils.
>    There's not much to do since he turned sixty-five,
>    So he took to his garden to keep him alive,
>    And I think it's his joy and his pride. — Bernie Perry, “The Man of the Earth” (song), 1977.

In more metaphorical or figurative contexts, the meaning of *man of the earth* depends on the value assigned to *earth*: for instance, a man bound to material things as opposed to heavenly, lofty, or “higher,” intellectual pursuits or a “man of earth” as opposed to one “with his head in the clouds.”

Comment: One modern place that uses a literal translation of the Biblical phrase (though not about Noah) is Andrew Lloyd Webber’s _Joseph and the Amazing Technicolour Dreamcoat_, where Jacob and his family are described as “men of the soil, of the sheaf and crook” (i.e., farmers and shepherds).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an unusual combination of the following two idioms, as indicated by Merriam-Webster.

[**Man of the world**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man%20of%20the%20world):

> : a practical or worldly-wise man of wide experience

[**The salt of the earth**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20salt%20of%20the%20earth):

> : a very good and honest person or group of people
>   // These folks are *the salt of the earth*.

---

Without any other context, we might assume that the author is combining the two. In other words, the man in question combined all of these qualities: he was wise, experienced, good, and honest.

It could also be taken in its literal sense (a farmer, or someone who works with the earth). However, the phrase *so to speak* suggests that it's more metaphorical.